# How to get color of bar object in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create a bar graph then use the color from the graph later for another graph

```py
bar = ax1.bar(np.delete(bin_edges, len(bin_edges)-1) + scalar * i, hist, width=scalar, align='center', label=key)
```

I have tried using .color and .get_color() both to no avail.

```py
color = bar.color
```

AttributeError: 'BarContainer' object has no attribute 'color'

```py
color = bar.get_color()
```

AttributeError: 'BarContainer' object has no attribute 'get_color'

Answer (score 6):

The `BarContainer` is an iterable of bars. Since those could in principle have all different colors, those would need to be obtained from the individual bars.

```
for bar in barcontainer:
    print(bar.get_facecolor())
```

Comment: Can square brackets be used to index a BarContainer? e.g bar[0].get_facecolor()

Comment: Yes... you can.

Comment: you can use `barcontainer[-1].get_facecolor()` to get the last color that was used.